# Order of arguments important for call optimization?

Tags: c++, x86-64, calling-convention, abi

I was researching an implementation of `std::function` analog from `EASTL` and came across this comment: [github.com/EASTL/function_detail.h#L348](https://github.com/electronicarts/EASTL/blob/05f4b4aef33f2f3ded08f19fa97f5a27ff35ff9f/include/EASTL/internal/function_detail.h#L348). As I understand it, the main idea of this "implicit" optimization is that the member functions are called in a specific way and a special register is used for `this`, which usually does not overlap with the data registers (those in which normal parameters are passed). But since they are using an external `Invoker` function to proxy the call, they are faced with having to shuffle parameters back and forth. Due to the fact that for the `Invoker`, the transferred `this` is an ordinary pointer, and therefore it is placed in the data register on a general basis. And so they came up with the idea of pulling `this` at the end so that other parameters are not touched later.

So I decided to try this approach in practice and implemented my poor man's version of `std::function`.

```
template <typename R, typename... Args>
struct [[nodiscard]] static_function<R(Args...)> final {
    using invoke_storage = std::array<std::byte, 8>;
    using invoke_pointer = R (*)(Args..., invoke_storage&) noexcept;

    invoke_storage storage;
    invoke_pointer invoke;

    template <typename Fn>
    constexpr static_function(Fn&& fn) noexcept
        : storage{std::bit_cast<invoke_storage>(padded{fn, constant<8>})}
        , invoke {invoker<Fn>} {}

    constexpr R operator()(Args... args) noexcept {
        return invoke(args..., storage);
    }

    template <typename Fn>
    static constexpr R invoker(Args... args, invoke_storage& storage) noexcept {
        return reinterpret_cast<Fn&>(storage)(args...);
    }
};
```

But I can't seem to reproduce this optimization. As I understand it, since this is part of the x64 ABI specification, it should work without additional optimizations from the compiler side, but even with compiler optimizations (`-O2`) asm output for `invoker` looks like this: [godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/oq7dG9o6Y)

```
int static_function<int (int, int)>::invoker<noinline_functor>(int, int, std::array<std::byte, 8ul>&):
        mov     rax, rdx
        mov     edx, esi
        mov     esi, edi
        mov     rdi, rax
        jmp     noinline_functor::operator()(int, int) const     # TAILCALL
```

What exactly am I doing wrong here? Is it because I'm using a byte array (to erase the type) + `reinterpret_cast`?

Comment: The most optimal method for passing arguments is not to have argument; or inline the function.  The next method involves registers.  There is no significant method for ordering the registers.  If you manage to optimize, you're talking a magnitude of nanoseconds.   If you have many parameters, you may want to place them into a structure and pass the structure.  In most of the compiler generated code I've seen, the compiler usually pushes a copy or registers to the stack, before any further code is executed.

Comment: From the linked page: "Assume we are using the Windows x64 Calling Convention." Your test uses the System V calling convention.

Comment: Have you considered using function *pointers* or function objects?  IMHO, function pointers are about as optimized as you can get.

Comment: @RaymondChen From the linked page: "This optimization works for any Calling Convention, we are just using Windows x64 for this example.", please read more carefully.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Yes, I understand your point of view, but still this question did not give me peace, from an academic point of view :)

Comment: @ThomasMatthews First of all, I wanted to check whether the optimization described above really works, at least in a vacuum. Function pointers are cool, but you can't use them with lambdas that have captured something.

Comment: I don't see how this should work here. After all your indirections, you invoke `noinline_functor::operator()`. That gets the `this` pointer as its first implicit argument, at least in SystemV calling convention; have to double check Win64. That `this` pointer is effectively the `invoke_storage` argument. So if that is the first argument in `R invoker(...)`, there is the least amount of register swapping

Comment: Did you check whether this assumption "a special register is used for this, which usually does not overlap with the data registers (those in which normal parameters are passed)" holds in your test environment?

Comment: @Homer512 I could be wrong, but `this` pointer should not be passed as the first argument. Because the `R invoker(...)` is an external entity in relation to callable.

Comment: You can see it in the code. Just swap the `invoke_storage` to the first parameter and the code is considerably smaller: https://godbolt.org/z/oMb8E9q1o

Comment: It *would* work if the end of your call chain is a plain function pointer, not a functor, because a function of course does not receive a pointer to itself as the first argument

Comment: @Homer512 Oh, got it. Haha, that is, if the call is via a function pointer, then this optimization will work, otherwise the registers will be shifted. And if I want it to work with lambdas, then `invoke_storage` needs to be passed as the first parameter so that register shifts don't happen as well.